# Mule - Error Handling

Tags: mule, mule-studio

In Mule I'm using a catch exception strategy referenced by a "complex" flow.
I put a jdbc component in the exception strategy, to update a table record in case of error
How can I access the exception stack trace to log it on this table?
I checked the payload at the beginning of the exception strategy and it is of type `org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod` in fact I got the error during an http call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the exception strategy exception is not available in the Payload.  It is available in the exceptionPayload variable of the Message object.

Use

Exception exception = (Exception)message.getExceptionPayload().getException();

This give ExceptionPaylaod object whose  getException() method provides the exception object.

To get the stack trace use the following.

```
StackTraceElement[] ste = exception.getCause().getStackTrace();
```

From there you can continue as your need.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful. I get a Mule exception message, that does not contain the java stack trace I see in the console (Root Exception stack trace:java.net.UnknownHostException). Is there a way to get it?

Comment: Moreover, in MEL, the current exception is bound under the `exception` variable.

Comment: Updated the answer with solution to get the StackTrace.

Comment: Thank you very much to both of you, I used the exception variable on a groovy script and exception.getCause().getStackTrace() to get the stackTrace.